# Knp paginator not paginating

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I'm having a problem getting the Knp paginator to advance to the next page. The page navigation bar shows up correctly as can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDgyQ.jpg) (names are fake), and the sorting works. But, when I try to advance to page 2, the view stays on page 1, even though the URL now looks like this: `my.page/show?page=2`

The view template is called by AttendeeController, which is imbedded in **show.html.twig**:

```
    <div class="attendance_table">

        {{ render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Attendee:index', { 'request': request, 'id': entity.id }
        )) }}

    </div>
```

**AttendeeController.php**:

```
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class AttendeeController extends Controller
    {

        public function indexAction(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $attendees = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Attendee')->findEventAttendees($id);
            $event = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')->findOneById($id);
           $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
           $pagination2 = $paginator->paginate(
           $attendees,
           $this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', 1), 10
        );



    return $this->render('Attendee/index.html.twig', array(
        'pagination2' => $pagination2,
        'event' => $event,
    ));
}
```

}

The controller calls a function **findEventAttendees** from AttendeeRepository, which finds attendees associated with an event:

```
    public function findEventAttendees($id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a')
        ->from('AppBundle:Attendee', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.event', 'e')
        ->where('e.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

The paginated view is rendered by **Attendee/index.html.twig**:

```
    {% if pagination2.getTotalItemCount > 0 %}
    <table class="records_list table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th {% if pagination2.isSorted('a.firstName') %} class="sorted" {% endif %}>
                {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination2, 'Name', 'a.firstName') }}
            </th >
            <th {% if pagination2.isSorted('a.uni') %} class="sorted" {% endif %}>
                {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination2, 'UNI', 'a.uni') }}
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for attendee in pagination2 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ attendee.firstName }} {{ attendee.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ attendee.uni }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {# display navigation #}
    <div class="text-center">
        {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination2) }}
    </div>

{% else %}
    <h2>Sorry, no attendees were found for the specified event.</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: try with the request passed to the command  `$request->query->getInt('page', 1)`  instead of this `$this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', 1)`

Comment: Hi @yvoloshin! You are welcome! Can I post the comment as an answer so you can close the question?

Comment: Sure @Matteo, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller, use the Request object passed as argument instead of the Request retrieved from the container.

So try this:

```
$request->query->getInt('page', 1);
```

instead of this :

```
$this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', 1);
```

Take the request from the container is a deprecated features. In [this annuncement](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack), Fabien saw:

> Dealing with the request in the service container is difficult to say
>   the least. Why is it difficult to inject the request into a service?
>   Because you can have more than one request in a single PHP process
>   (think sub-requests.) So, during the lifetime of the container, the
>   request instance changes.

Hope this help